# Run-time error '1004' when script is ran from PERSONAL.XLSB

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA script that works fine when it's in a module within a workbook, but if I put it in a module in my `PERSONAL.XLSB` file, I get this error:

Run-time error '1004':

> Cannot rename a sheet to the same name as another sheet, a referenced
>   object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic

This is apparently the offending portion of the script that is creating the error:

```
.Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)).Name = "ValidateData"
```

This script is to be used in many workbooks, so in order for that to work, I feel like it has to be in the `PERSONAL.XLSB` file. I don't understand why the error only comes up when it's coming from that file and not its own file.

And just to be clear, there isn't already a worksheet called ValidateData at this point in this script.

Comment: You'll likely need to post more of the code.  You don't happen to have "a referenced object library or a workbook referenced by Visual Basic" named "ValidateData", do you?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add the sheet to the PERSONAL.XLSB file, unless you have a qualifier above what you posted.

Comment: Ah. I bet that is it. Maybe I'll have to make a separate question for this, but how can I make add the sheet to a different one? To be clear, when I open any Excel spreadsheet, PERSONAL.XLSB automatically opens as well, kind of in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Use **`SheetExists Function`** Function returns TRUE if sheet exists in the active workbook

Example

```
Public Sub Add_Sheet()
    Dim SName As String

    SName = "ValidateData"

    If SheetExists(SName) = False Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count)).Name = SName
    Else
        MsgBox SName & " Sheet Already Exsit"
    End If

End Sub

Function SheetExists(SName As String, _
                     Optional ByVal WB As Workbook) As Boolean
'Chip Pearson
    On Error Resume Next
    If WB Is Nothing Then Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
    SheetExists = CBool(Len(WB.Sheets(SName).Name))
End Function
```

Comment: @Robby answer revised